# How can I get a one-digit random number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, random, digits

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

How can I get one-digit random numbers (1, 2, 3, ..., not 0.1, 0.2, ... or 1.0, 5.0, ...) using Math.random() or some other way in JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicates: [Generating random numbers in Javascript in a specific range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/), [Random between two numbers in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959975), [Random number between -10 and 10 in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594177),

Comment: Should 0 (zero) be included or not? [JohannesB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122894/how-can-i-get-a-one-digit-random-number-in-javascript/14123012#14123012) covers both possibilities.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Math.random()` returns a float between `0` and `1`, so just multiply it by `10` and turn it into an integer:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
```

Or something a little shorter:

```
~~(Math.random() * 10)
```

Comment: nice, didn't knew about the `~~` operator

Answer (score 7):

## *Disclaimer*:

> JavaScript's math.rand() is **not** cryptographically secure, meaning that this should ***not*** be used for password, PIN-code and/or gambling related random number generation. If this is your use case, please use the web [crypto API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651789/is-math-random-cryptographically-secure#5651854) instead! ([W3C](https://w3c.github.io/webcrypto/)).

---

If the digit 0 is not included (1-9):

```
function randInt() {
    return Math.floor((Math.random()*9) + 1);
}
```

If the digit 0 is included (0-9):

```
function randIntWithZero() {
     return Math.floor((Math.random()*10));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10)
```

where 10 dictates that the random number will fall between 0-9.

Comment: 10 is not one digit, is it?

Comment: lol, no, but assuming it's the fractional part the OP does not want they can work it out! Edited.

Comment: For anyone wondering, the `Math.random()` function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range 0–1 (inclusive of 0, but not 1), so this won't return 10.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Math.floor((Math.random()*9)+1);
```

Comment: That `+ 1` removes `0` and adds `10` to the possible outputs.

Comment: The question said "digit", so I think it meant `0-9`.

Comment: @Blender well you are right about `10` not being a digit. I've corrected it accordingly but the OP's example did not include `0` so I think this is alright.

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.floor((Math.random()*10));
```

And there goes your random integer between 0 and 10!

Comment: (Posted approx. 6 seconds after Paul Collingwood's answer.)

Comment: "between 0 and 10" is somewhat ambiguous. Is 0 included or not? As 10 is excluded, it would suggest 0 is excluded as well.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Nope, 0 is included, but 10 isn't. The author's wording is incorrect.