# Normalization of a decimal value

Tags: c#, histogram, scaling, gaussian, minmax

My problem is like this: I need to generate a random number from Gaussin/Norma distribution and create a histogram of a width of 0.1.

```
class Gaussian
{
    public static double Next(Random r, double mu = 0, double sigma = 1)
    {
        var u1 = r.NextDouble();
        var u2 = r.NextDouble();

        var rand_std_normal =   Math.Sqrt(-2.0 * Math.Log(u1)) *
                                Math.Sin(2.0 * Math.PI * u2);

        var rand_normal = mu + sigma * rand_std_normal;

        return rand_normal;
    }
}
```

I am using the above function to generate a Gaussian random value.

Now, in order to create a histogram, I am in need of such a calculation that is able to automatically convert the gaussian value into an array index. Something like the following:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int N = 1000;
        int time = N;
        const double binsDistance = 0.1;
        int binsCount = (int)(N * binsDistance);

        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] array = new int[binsCount];
        int side = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < time; i++)
        {
            double gauss = Gaussian.Next(rand);
            int binNo = Normalization.Normalize(0, binsCount - 1, gauss);
            array[binNo]++;
        }
    }
```

For that, I tried two calculations.

1. the [first one is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3594189/159072).
2. the [second one is here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70807/109372).

The problem with the first one is, it can't handle negative numbers properly.

The problem with the second one is, it is generating too many zero values.

So, I have two questions:

1. What is the basic difference between #1 and #2?
2. How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: First, Method 1 is for converting a number from 0 to 1 into a number from min to max, and so is not appropriate for a number from `Double.MinValue` to `Double.MaxValue`.

Comment: Where did you get your Gaussian calculation? There seems something funny about it - the more you call it, the wider than range.

Comment: @NetMage, https://bitbucket.org/Superbest/superbest-random/src/master/Superbest%20random/RandomExtensions.cs